# Trigger on UPDATE to DELETE rows in another table depending on a third table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, sql-delete

I am trying to create trigger for the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.first (
 userid bigint,
 name varchar
);

 CREATE TABLE public.second (
 userid bigint,
 companyid bigint
);

CREATE TABLE public.visibility_matrix (
 name varchar,
 companyid bigint
);
```

Whenever a row in the table `first` is updated, the trigger should take the `userid` and search for the same `userid` in table `second`. If that exists, then delete the row/rows from `visibility_matrix` where the `companyid` is extracted from the table 'second'.

Here is what I tried:

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pos_org_rel_refresh()
  RETURNS trigger AS  
$$  
DECLARE
  r Integer ;

BEGIN  

 IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN

DELETE FROM visibility_matrix where companyid=NEW.companyid;
RETURN NEW;

  END IF;
END;
$$  
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger  
AFTER UPDATE 
ON first
FOR EACH ROW  
EXECUTE PROCEDURE pos_org_rel_refresh();
```

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Employ the [`USING` clause of `DELETE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html) to join in another table:

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pos_org_rel_refresh()
  RETURNS trigger AS  
$func$
-- DECLARE
--    r int;  -- not used in function body
BEGIN  
-- IF TG_OP='UPDATE' THEN  -- redundant while func is only used in AFTER UPDATE trigger
   DELETE FROM public.visibility_matrix v
   USING  public.second s
   WHERE  s.userid = NEW.userid
   AND    v.companyid = s.companyid;
-- END IF;

RETURN NEW;  --  and don't place this inside the IF block either way

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;  -- don't quote the language name
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger  
AFTER UPDATE ON first
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE pos_org_rel_refresh();
```